StoreKit 2: User to user auto-renewing subscriptions
We have an iOS app with features similar to a blog or most social apps, ie creators can make posts. We want to allow other users to be able to subscribe to a creator to access their premium content, eg the OnlyFans model.
After reading through a ton of threads and docs, I used to think user-to-user auto-renewing subscriptions weren't possible with In-App Purchases for a few reasons, the main one being that every subscription group has to be created by the app developer and reviewed by Apple before it can be used. I even contacted RevenueCat to ask about this and they said it wasn't possible without using a 3rd party payment service like Stripe, which we all know is a good way to get removed from the app store.
Recently I'm starting to see more iOS apps supporting this model, such as Instagram and Patreon. I'm thinking something may have changed, but I'm not sure what. Does anyone know how these big companies are implementing auto-renewing user-to-user subscriptions with In-App Purchases?

+1! It's really interesting topic. JFYI: I tried on the Instagram Android app and it just seems to use Billing Library (regardless it's using RevenueCat or not). Thus it must not be any 3rd party solution like Stripe.

@Toru Is Billing Library Google's answer to Apple In-App Purchases?

Sorry, I don't get well what you mean

@Toru I mean is Billing Library the native Android way for selling digital content. I did some quick research and it looks like it is. I'm not familiar with Google's policies in this area, but if Instagram is using In-App Purchases for user-to-user subscriptions on iOS I'd love to know how.

I see. I came up with an idea so I'll post it as an answer.

As you may know, there's a policy in the App Store that allows external payment methods for certain categories of apps as written here.

3.1.3 Other Purchase Methods: The following apps may use purchase methods other than in-app purchase.

I think it is most probably the case for Patreon. However, Instagram should be a different story.
I have tried to purchase a subscription from the iOS app and it looks like the screenshot. It shows an ordinal purchasing sheet so they must be using IAP but the item name is Instagram Subscriptions 368... a bit weird huh?

Next, this picture is the IAP items displayed on the Instagram page in the App Store. As you can see, there are a lot of subscriptions named Instagram Subscriptions ${number} and also prices are so duplicated.

Given them all, this is the best guess I can make at the moment on how Instagram implements person-to-person (1:n) subscriptions.

A creator creates(more like apply/submit) a subscription in the App.
Then Instagram creates a corresponding subscription in App Store Connect (should be automated by App Store Connect API) and submits a review to Apple under the hood.
Once it's approved it's shown in the creator's profile screen and users can subscribe to it in the App.

What's your take on this? If we can know how the system (especially UI/UX) works on the creator side, it must be clue as well.

I think there's a good chance you're right. I've thought of this too, but I haven't been able to even get as far as the paywall screen on Instagram to prove it (subscriptions seem to be waitlisted where I am). My main reservation is that Apple only allows a maximum of 10,000 In-App Purchase products, and for an app like Instagram I feel they would run out pretty quick. I'm not sure how they would get around that, unless they have a special deal with Apple. Still, I think I will try out this solution. Thanks for investigating.

@Grambo "Apple only allows a maximum of 10,000 In-App Purchase products" That's a good point I had missed. If you find another way, it would be great if you could share it with us.

We tried building this for our fashion creator app and ran into the same problem. The best solution was to implement peer-to-peer subscriptions with Stripe. You can have a parent organization and have creators self-serve. Patreon allows for viewing but routes people to pay online only.

Interesting. So you were able to successfully implement using Stripe within your app and Apple didn't remove you from the App Store for not using IAPs?
As per Patreon, we were thinking of that route, but it's frustrating how Apple won't allow us to direct users from within our app to the payment portal on a website without getting flagged. We have to "hope" they discover it on their own, or at best from our emails. It's a solution, but not an ideal one.
